# Prevent Intrinsic Content Size in UIStackView

Tags: ios9, xcode7, uistackview

I start with an empty vertical stack view and a button larger than its intrinsic content size.  Dragging the button into the stack view results in it changing to its intrinsic content size.  A work around for this is to add spaces before and after the button's title.
Is there a better way to do this?

What I want is the button in the stack view to look like this:
[image: button inside stack view]

Not this:
[image: button inside stack view]

Yes, you can put a constraint on the Button's length, but I do not want to do this.  The idea of UIStackView is to have it take care of the necessary constraints for you.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be the best way to do it in a generic sense, for your specific use case you could set the `contentEdgeInsets` of your button:

```
self.myButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0);
```

This will still use the *intrinsicContentSize*, but it will give you the padding you are looking for. If you want an exact width regardless of the button's title, then this isn't going to be the right solution for you.